# If $f(x)$ is the square root of the number that is $2$ more than $x,$ what is the value of $f(7) - f(-1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

> If $f(x)$ is defined for all $x>-2$ as the square root of the number that is $2$ more than $x$, what is the value of $f(7) - f(-1)$?

**My attempted solution:**

$f(x) = \sqrt{x + 2}$

Now, $f(7) = \sqrt{7 + 2} = \pm3$

and,

$f(-1) = \sqrt{-1 + 2} = \pm1$.

So, $f(7) - f(-1) = 2, 4, -4, -2$.

Given answer is, $2$ only.

**Why?**

Comment: Because the square root of a non-negative real number is...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, what is the sqrt of 4?

Comment: @yahoo.com The square root of $4$ is $2$.

Comment: @egreg, but $2^2 = (-2)^2 = 4$

Comment: By convention, when dealing with real numbers, "the square root of" and the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ refer to the non-negative square root.

Comment: @yahoo.com So what? Under the most common convention, the square root of $x$ is the *unique* nonnegative number whose square is $x$.

Comment: @yahoo.com Would you prefer that $\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{1}$ is any of $-2$, $0$ or $2$? Or that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$ has (at most) eight values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given answer is taking what is referred to as the *principal square root*, rather like $x=\frac{\pi}{6}^c$ or $x=30^0$ is the principal root of $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, there are many other solutions, but this is the one that is most commonly used, and given by calculatorss.

In this question, it is standard to use the principal square root for equations like these. Hence we get $\sqrt{9}=3, \sqrt{1}=1$, thus $f(7)-f(-1)=3-1=2$

Answer (score 1):

It is a convention that for $a>0$, if
$$b=\sqrt a$$, then $b>0$.

In some articles, $b$ is called the **principal value** of square root, distinguishing it from the other possible value, $-b$.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of $1$ is $1$, not $±1$
and so is the square root of $9$.

So the answer will be $3-1 = 2$

Comment: what is the sqrt of 4?

Comment: $-1$ is a perfectly good square root of $1$ and $-3$ is a perfectly good square root of $9$. What you should be explaining to the OP is that, by convention, a phrase like "square root of $x$" is usually taken to refer to the non-negative square root.

Comment: but we have been taught that the sqrt of a positive number is a positive number.

Comment: my life is a lie

Comment: @AvnishSingh You were not told a lie. `:-)`

Comment: @RobArthan: No. $-1$ is not a valid square root of $1$. Say us: which is the solution for $x^2-1=0$?

Comment: @AvnishSingh, the square root of positive number can be a positive number, but it can also be a negative number

Comment: @Dog_69 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ndjn0dr4h3. What exactly is your point?

Comment: @RhysHughes: Write the solution. And consider the equation $x^2-2=0$ better.

Comment: @Dog_69 $x=\pm1$

Comment: For that one, it would be $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$

Comment: So you are assuming that the square root is positive. Otherwise you don't write the symbol $\pm$.

Comment: haha caught ya @rhyshughes

Comment: nice one @dog_69

Comment: @Dog_69 In what way am I assuming that. I'm saying that the *principal value* is positive, but I could just as easily say it's negative and have the $\pm$ cover both.

Comment: No. If you say that it is negative you cover the negative. And then you have to writhe the $\pm$ again. The point is that $\sqrt x$ only have one value. If not, ir isn't a function.